# Filtro condicionado Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Tengo un formulario ligado a una base de datos con muchos datos, y distintos campos para filtrar (*Matrícula, Trabajador, Proyecto*).

Quiero conseguir que si selecciono el campo *Trabajador* con x nombre, en el campo *Proyectos* salgan solo los proyectos que le correspondan a dicho trabajador, y no todos los disponibles.

No sé realmente si esto se puede conseguir, ya que he estado bastantes días buscando una solución a esto, pero sin resultados.

Este es el código actual:

```
    Private Sub txtMatricula_AfterUpdate()
    Dim miSQL As String
    Dim miFiltro As String
    Dim i As Long

    miFiltro = ""

    For i = 0 To Me.txtMatricula.ItemsSelected.Count - 1
        miFiltro = miFiltro & "MATRICULA='" & Me.txtMatricula.ItemData(Me.txtMatricula.ItemsSelected.Item(i)) & "' AND "
    Next
    If Len(miFiltro) > 0 Then
        miFiltro = Mid$(miFiltro, 1, Len(miFiltro) - 5)
        miSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT PROYECTO AS PRO FROM CTrabajadores WHERE " & miFiltro & " ORDER BY PROYECTO"
    Else
    miSQL = ""
    End If

    Me.txtProyecto.RowSource = miSQL
    Me.txtProyecto.Requery
End Sub
```

En cambio, cuando selecciono una matrícula, el campo de Proyecto me sale en blanco, cuando deberían salir los resultados de dicha matrícula

Comment: Entiendo que estás aplicando esto en un formulario. Las fechas a mí muchas veces me dan problemas, y lo que hago es transformarlas a número y me funciona de lujo. Así evito almohadillas y otros y solo uso criterios lógicos como `>,<,>=, etc.`. PAra transformar a número, uso Cdbl(). ¿Cómo es el recordset de origen de esto?

Comment: En principio no hay ningún problema con el filtro de fechas, funciona perfectamente tal y como está. Lo que quiero conseguir es como un "Filtro condicional" en los campos Matrícula, Trabajador y Proyecto @ElierSánchezE-Infantes

Comment: De access estoy un poco oxidado pero has probado a ir paso a paso ejecutando el código que expones?
Si vas paso a paso mira el valor de "miFiltro" cuando vayas pasando por el IF...THen. Si miFiltro tiene un valor/texto copia el resultado de la consulta entera: ""SELECT DISTINCT PROYECTO AS PRO FROM CTrabajadores WHERE " & miFiltro & " ORDER BY PROYECTO" y pégala en una nueva consulta de access, a ver si obtienes resultados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el campo Proyecto modifiqué el origen de la fila (A los 3 puntos), seleccionando "PROYECTO" (Campo que queremos que saque los resultados dependientes) y "TRABAJADOR" (Campo del que dependerá).

Relacionamos ambas tablas/consultas. Sacamos los totales en la consulta, dejamos "PROYECTO" como "Agrupar por" y "TRABAJADOR" lo cambiamos por "Dónde". Luego, marcamos como Criterio de "TRABAJADOR" la casilla de la que dependerá en el formulario.

`[Formularios]![Menu]![txtTrabajador]`

En el formulario, creamos un evento Después de Actualizar en el campo "TRABAJADOR", y añadimos el siguiente código que hará que carguen los resultados dependiendo del resultado del campo.

```
Proyecto_DepM.Value = Null
Proyecto_DepM.Requery
```

Y con eso, al seleccionar un resultado en "Trabajador", cambiarán los resultados de "Proyecto", dependiendo de los que les correspondan.